# Cylindrical shells problem, where did my math go wrong?

Tags: integration, volume

$y= x^2$, $y= 6x-2x^2$

rotated about the $y$-axis. and this is in the cylindrical shells chapter of my book.

so I solve  $x^2 = 6x-2x^2$ and I get $x = 0$ and $x= 2$

so volume for cylindrical shells is = to the integral of (circumference)(height)(thickness), correct?

so I have $2\pi$ integral of $\int x(6x-3x^2) dx$

I got $6x-3x^2$ by subtracting inner function from outer

so I went ahead and integrated $\int6x^2 - 3x^3 dx$ and got

$3x^3 - \frac{3}{4}x^4$ from $2$ to $0$

which gave me an answer of $12$, which I multiplied by $2\pi$ to get $24\pi$.

But my book is telling me the answer is $8\pi$. How did they get this?

Comment: The flaw is in saying that $\int 6x^2 dx = 3x^3$. It's actually $2x^3$, which should give you the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you bro. I can't believe I'm in calculus 2 but still overlook these type of things. Thank you man I was stressing hard on this.

Comment: Don't worry, it took me a minute to find it too :P